# What are distinctive typological features of Uralic?

Tags: linguistic-typology, uralic

Many grammatical features of Uralic are shared with Turkic, Tungusic and/or Mongolic, while some of those that are not are nevertheless shared by indigenous Siberian language families.

What are examples of typologically distinctive features of the Uralic family that are neither "Altaic" nor commonly found in Siberian languages?

Maybe the objective conjugation would be an example of this.

Comment: There seems to be no distinctive typological feature that _all_ the Uralic languages share, have a look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uralic_languages#Comparison